# Jquery UI autocomplete is not working when first time page loading

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

My html page contains one document search text box, which auto complete the document name based on user input. The document names are coming from the server side script through Ajax call. The following code which is working fine , but the only problem is when user opens new browser and enters 3 chars auto complete suggestions not populating. if user enters 4 chars it working, after that user enters 3 chars also it working fine.

```
$('#global-doc-search-box').keyup(function(e){
   thisObj.searchGlobalDocuments(e);
});

$("#global-doc-search-box").autocomplete({
    source: [{value: 'test', id: 'test', label: 'test'}],                           
    delay: 0
}).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {  
   return $("<li></li>")
   .append("<div style='background-color: #fff;display:block;min-width:200px;padding: 10px;'><a style='text-decoration: none;' href='#' target='_blank'>" + item.value + "</a></div></li>")
   .appendTo(ul);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my problem. I just removed explicit keyup event, we don't need any explicit key event listner, seems like key event listening is implicitly configured in autocomplete function.